# What does symbol '||' mean in query

Tags: sql, criteria-api

I have the following criteria api query before populating parametrs

```
 where lower(generatedAlias7.personGivenName || :param6 || generatedAlias7.personSurName) like :param7)
```

Can anyone explain what does it mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some vendors (e.g. Oracle or PostgreSQL I think) offer the double bar || operator to concatenate strings.

Comment: Google seems to imply Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed string concatenation but it is seems to be jpql query and it is not related to any vendor. Or I am wrong about jpql string ).

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the jpql way would be the "CONCAT" function. I dont think the '||' operator is standard. Didn't try it though.